# Linux - Split textfile along new line

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a testfile similar to this one:

```
   Bla: Blubb
   Bla: blubb

   Relevant stuff
```

So basically header information followed by a newline. I need everything after the newline as the number of header-lines varies.

Does anybody have an idea on how to achieve that?

Cheers and thank you
Fabian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '1,/^\s*$/d' file
```

Comment: Actually only this one worked. I'm not sure why as I have seen the answers aboves in similar questions. In my case (or rather with my file) they all printed nothing at all. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

With sed

```
sed -n '/^$/,$p' file
```

With awk (including the newline):

```
awk '/^$/{p=1};p' file
```

With awk (excluding the newline):

```
awk 'p;/^$/{p=1}' file
```

Comment: I'm sure these work on the right file. However they did not on mine. But thank you anyways :)

Comment: It's probably because there are Windows line breaks or some extra spaces / tabs. You could analyse the file by examing the characters with `xxd`.